# print possible all path in graph in python using dictionaries

Tags: python, graph

i try to make a graph program using python to print all possible path from x to y. i want to show all path from 9 to 29, but the program did not print it. maybe anyone can help to fixed it. here the code.

```
graph =     {'0': ['3', '10','1'],
             '1': ['10', '0','4'],
             '2': ['8','6','3'],
             '3': ['17','2','9','0'],
             '4': ['1','5'],
             '5': ['4','12','7'],
             '6': ['17','2'],
             '7': ['5','22'],
             '8': ['13','2'],
             '9': ['3','17','10'],
             '10': ['9','17','0','1','11'],
             '11': ['20','12'],
             '12': ['5','11'],
             '13': ['8','14','16'],
             '14': ['13'],
             '15': ['16','17'],
             '16': ['13','15','17'],
             '17': ['16','6','3','9','10','15','18','23','24'],
             '18': ['17','25','19'],
             '19': ['26','18','20'],
             '20': ['28','19','21'],
             '21': ['28','20','22'],
             '22': ['7'],
             '23': ['17','24'],
             '24': ['17','23','27'],
             '25': ['27','18','26'],
             '26': ['25','19'],
             '27': ['24','25','29'],
             '28': ['29','20','21'],
             '29': ['27','28']}

def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return path
        if start not in graph:
            return None
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpath = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
                if newpath: return newpath
        return None
find_path(graph,'9','29')
```

i'm not sure in part of method to find it. i need your opinion where did I go wrong?. thanks

Comment: You are not printing anything :)

Just change last line to something like: `print(find_path(graph, '9', '29'))`

Comment: thank you, i forget it :v, but the result got wrong. can you help me to fixed it @Syler

Comment: Hello! One of the things that really helps other people is if you embed your code directly in the question. That way, in your dpaste bin breaks one day, your code will remain intact in the question. For formatting, just be sure to wrap your code with ``` and you will be all set.

Comment: @rey this is what i got: `['9', '3', '17', '10', '0', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '28', '29']`. Seems like a legit path. How is this wrong?

Comment: do you have a telegram account?, let me give the problem in direct massage @Syler

Comment: Just post it here, please.

Comment: there's a picture cant post it cause it's over 2mb@Syler

Comment: can't post it cause over my image over 2mb @Corralien

Comment: Look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400996/python-using-dictionary-to-define-a-graph-and-find-paths). A solution was accepted for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `networkx` package, the problem  become much more straightforward. Even if you do not want to use `networkx`, you have the solution yet to fix your code.

```
# Python env: pip install networkx
# Anaconda env: conda install network
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_dict_of_lists(graph)
all_paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, '9', '29'))

for path in all_paths:  # <- # 1060 paths!!!
    print(path)
```

```
['9', '3', '0', '10', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '19', '18', '17', '23', '24', '27', '29']
['9', '3', '0', '10', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '19', '18', '17', '24', '27', '29']
['9', '3', '0', '10', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '19', '18', '25', '27', '29']
['9', '3', '0', '10', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '19', '26', '25', '18', '17', '23', '24', '27', '29']
['9', '3', '0', '10', '1', '4', '5', '12', '11', '20', '19', '26', '25', '18', '17', '24', '27', '29']
...
['9', '10', '11', '12', '5', '7', '22', '21', '28', '20', '19', '18', '25', '27', '29']
['9', '10', '11', '12', '5', '7', '22', '21', '28', '20', '19', '26', '25', '18', '17', '23', '24', '27', '29']
['9', '10', '11', '12', '5', '7', '22', '21', '28', '20', '19', '26', '25', '18', '17', '24', '27', '29']
['9', '10', '11', '12', '5', '7', '22', '21', '28', '20', '19', '26', '25', '27', '29']
['9', '10', '11', '12', '5', '7', '22', '21', '28', '29']
```